# use INSERT inside definition of VIEW: CREATE VIEW AS INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, insert-into

If I want to do something relatively complicated - something usually done by a stored procedure. Is it possible to make it automatic using a `VIEW`?

**My specific case:**

I want output table = input table A + some rows input table B. In a stored procedure, I can make a copy of table A and then `INSERT INTO` it, but it's not allowed in a view.

**Simplified example:**

input table is `[test_album]`, and output table = input table + singer Prince.

```
--create test data
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[test_album]', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[test_album] 

CREATE TABLE [test_album] ( 
    id int not null identity(1, 1) primary key, 
    singer VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    album_title VARCHAR(100) NULL 
    ) 

INSERT INTO [test_album] (singer, album_title) 
    VALUES ('Adale', '19'), 
        ('Michael Jaskson', 'Thriller')

--this can be executed as sql code or in stored proc
SELECT *
INTO [result_table]
FROM [test_album]

INSERT INTO [result_table] ([singer])
    VALUES ('Prince') 

select *
from [result_table]
--id    singer  album_title
--1 Adale   19
--2 Michael Jaskson Thriller
--3 Prince  NULL
----as expected
```

But I can do this `INSERT INTO` inside a view.

**Real-life case:**

additional singers are in a table [extra_singers]

[test_album] may have many other columns (or schema may change) so it's ideal not to type all column names in the code.

```
--create test data
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[test_album]', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[test_album] 
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[extra_singers]', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[extra_singers] 
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[result_table]', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[result_table]         

CREATE TABLE [test_album] ( 
    id int not null identity(1, 1) primary key, 
    singer VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    album_title VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    many_other_columns VARCHAR(100) NULL
    ) 

INSERT INTO [test_album] (singer, album_title) 
    VALUES ('Adale', '19'), 
        ('Michael Jaskson', 'Thriller')


CREATE TABLE [extra_singers] ( 
    [id] int not null identity(1, 1) primary key, 
    [name] VARCHAR(50) NULL )

INSERT INTO [extra_singers] ([name]) 
    VALUES ('Prince'), 
        ('Taylor Swift')


--append [extra_singers] to [test_album]
--this can be executed as sql code or in stored proc
SELECT *
INTO [result_table]
FROM [test_album]

INSERT INTO [result_table] ([singer])
    SELECT [name]
    FROM [extra_singers]
```

Is there an alternative to this (that is automatic)?
any help's appreciated. Thank u-

---

**a partial solution** I can think of:

```
create view test_view as

    select * 
    from [test_album]

    union all

    select 3 as id,
        'Prince' as singer,
        NULL as album_title
```

but you have to know all the column names in `[test_album]` and you can't let column [id] do auto-increment

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Can you clarify?

Comment: Views are meant to display the underlying data.  Inserting wouldn't really be appropriate for that.  A stored procedure would be better suited for what you are trying to do if you don't want to insert the data directly.

Comment: @SqlZim I need to add a row to a table each time I use it. I try to automate this using `VIEW`. So the view should = input table + one extra row

Comment: thank you @indiri is there any way to make is passively automatic like a view? any alternative to do the job? thank you-

Comment: Are you trying to input every time it's used (someone queries the view 100 times and it inserts 100 rows) or are you wanting it to just return whatever is in the table + one additional row no matter how many times it's queried?

Comment: You can fix the auto-increment with UNION ALL SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS id, 'Prince' as singer, NULL as album_title FROM [test_album]

Comment: @indiri thank you so much for your help~ If I put the work in a stored procedure, is it possible to automate it - whenever people want to see `output table`, it's calculated as `table A` + additional rows from `table B`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you may be misunderstanding what a `view` does, or what an `insert` is. A view is simply a wrapper around a single select query. It contains exactly one `select` statement, and nothing else. An `insert` permanently adds a row of data to a persisted table. The example you gave where you just union the row you want seems valid enough. And certainly if it's the same row you want every time, you would not want to be inserting (or even trying to insert) that row into the underlying table each time

This raises a couple questions though.

- If you're always going to be unioning the same single row every time, why not jut add that row to the table?
- If, lets say, you don't want that row in the underlying table, cool. But if it's always the same static values, why do you need to include it in the view? Can't it just be assumed it's there?
- If it can't be assume to always be the same, you certainly don't want to be changing the `VIEW` body every time you need it to change. So if it *is* going to change and you don't want to insert it into the base table, maybe make a second table containing the values you want appended to the base table in the view. Then union the base table and the "extra values" table together instead of a single, hard coded row constructor.

Comment: thank you @Xedni - clarified a lot for me!   My real-life case is `output table` = input `table A` + some additional rows based on `table B`. My colleagues may update `table A` and `table B`, and I was trying to make it automatic so I don't need to append it from time to time.